# Positive Definite Matrix Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having some little difficulties to show the following:

Let $M$ be a symmetric positive square matrix. I must show that $I-M$ is positive definite matrix if and only if $M^{-1}-I$ is positive definite.

Comment: You can assume that $M$ is diagonal. Can you solve it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that M is Symmetric Positive Definite, Implying that the eigenvalues are all positive. This argument works backwards too. (This would not be true if M were not Symmetric in general)
\begin{align}
\rightarrow\\
\because M \text{ is PD, }\\
\lambda_i&>0\quad \forall i\\
eig(I-M)&=(1-\lambda_i)\\\because(I-M)\text{ is PD, }\\
(1-\lambda_i)&>0\\
\implies 1&>\lambda_i>0\quad \forall i\\
eig(M^{-1}-I)&=\dfrac{1}{\lambda_i}-1\\
&>0\\
\implies (M^{-1}-I) \text{ is PD}
\end{align}
Similarly, you can do the reverse direction.

Comment: thanks a lot. I never noticed that $eig(I-M)=eig(I)-eig(M)$

Comment: Yeah. Not very difficult to prove : 
\begin{align}
Mx&=\lambda x\\ (M+I-I)x &= \lambda x \\ (M+I)x - Ix &= \lambda x \\ (M+I)x &= (\lambda + 1 ) x 
\end{align}